# How do I see my git remote url?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm sure this is a very silly question, but I searched here and online and couldn't find an answer. 
I have a project setup in intellij to some git server, I just want to see the details (e.g. to send to someone else the URL so they can clone etc...) how do I simply display the current project's git remote settings **within Intellij IDEA, not using the command line**? (version 14)

Or do I have to go to the command line for that? (I know how to do it in the git command line)

Comment: Try `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 77):

try

```
git remote show origin
```

it will show the URL or the remote repo

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there is a non command line option within Intellij IDEA to do so. p.s. isn't that `git remote show origin`?

Comment: this command is hanging...

Comment: This command does not work when the URL is incorrect. Best is the answer by @ALLSYED with a simple cat to the config file. Another option is `git remote -v`

Answer (score 23):

**Intellij IDEA Git remote URL**

In `Android Studio(3.1.2)` that is based on `Intellij IDEA` you can do

```
VCS -> Git -> Remotes...
//or
Git -> Manage Remotes...
```

[image]

Answer (score 21):

In WebStorm (almost same GUI like IntelliJ) it is done by clicking (Main menu) ->VCS->Git->Pull...

there you have the Remote url in the dialog window that appears.

Answer (score 7):

**You need only the remote repository URL, try below command in your terminal:**

```
git config --get remote.origin.url
```

**If you need all details and you are on a network that can reach the remote repository where the origin resides:**

```
git remote show origin
```

**Using `git remote show` will display the information about this remote name. The first few lines should show:**

```
C:\Users\tejassavaliya\my-example> git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.tejassavaliya/my-example.git
  Push  URL: git@github.tejassavaliya/my-example.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
```

Answer (score 6):

In **IntelliJ 2020.3** you can click Git/Manage Remotes:

[image]

And the origin is displayed:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In order to find remote url, or you are connected to internet and want to know the url you can use below command where your .git folder placed

`git config --get remote.origin.url`

of if you want to see the full out put and you have the internet then you can use below command

`git remote show origin`

it will show you the URL that a local Git repository was originally cloned from.

hope this help

Answer (score 1):

I would disconnect the internet connection, usually by turning off WiFi or switching to Airplane mode.

```bash
git pull
# or 
git fetch
```

I will be presented with error message.
It is very unconventional but it get the job done.

> fatal: unable to access <URL>

Alternatively I can also

```bash
cat .git/config
```

remote url can be seen in remote section.

Answer (score 0):

**git remote show origin**

It works perfect for me.